# How to explode a line and then explode it again to insert it into a database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

Im trying to explode a line where ":" is the first thing to explode and i need to put the 2 pieces into a database after. Then it should read the next line and do the same with that line.

```
$ex = explode(":", $list);
$array = array($ex);
$ex2   = explode("\r\n", $array);


foreach ($array as $acc)
{
    $data  = "INSERT INTO `accounts` (username, password) VALUES('$acc[0]', '$acc[1]')";
    $query = mysql_query($data);
}
```

Here is a example of what im trying to do: whodeynati85@yahoo.com:strokeme1

Make that into:
whodeynati85@yahoo.com
strokeme1

Then input the pieces into the Database.
Then look on next line and do the same.

whodeynati85@yahoo.com:strokem221     <-- Explode - Insert

tim@currentelectricsupply.com:3gir2ls <-- Explode - Insert

eliasevans@fuse.net:eulee1922         <-- Explode - Insert

tony@braswellscale.com:Abbey82822     <-- Explode - Insert

Comment: Where are those lines which you are trying to explode coming from?

Comment: You really should consider using SQL parameters to sanitize your SQL-input. Otherwise you might get SQL-injections, and that's a real bad thing to have.

Comment: Also consider moving to mysqli instead, since mysql-commands are getting deprecated [PHP.Net - Choosing an API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

Comment: Okey but thats not the problem here.

Answer (score 5):

I think your explodes are backwards. First you want to explode $list by '\r\n' to get the individual rows. Then, for each row, explode by ':' to get the pieces of data. I'd also highly highly highly highly recommend not storing passwords as plaintext.

```
$lines = explode("\r\n", $list);

foreach ($lines as $nextLine) {
    $lineVals = explode(":", $nextLine);
    $lineVals[1] = sha1($lineVals[1]);
    $data  = "INSERT INTO `accounts` (username, password) VALUES('$lineVals[0]', '$lineVals[1]')";
    $query = mysql_query($data);
}
```

And holy crap I hope that isn't real user account information.

Comment: Hehe no its just a test :) ofcourse i will encrypt my inputs :D

Comment: Looks like you don't have a \r\n between lines, then. Try doing a replace of \r\n with just \n and then exploding by \n.